# Calling a view function on different nodes

Tags: solidity, proof-of-stake

This question came up reading the specifics of view functions in solidity (https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/erc20-annotated-code/):

> This function is also a view, which means that it does not change the state, so it can be executed on a single node instead of having every node in the blockchain run it. This kind of function does not generate a transaction and does not cost gas.

Does this imply that when I call a view function from different node I could get different results if they are not in sync? Or is it that it only returns the state of finalized blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

> Does this imply that when I call a view function from different node I could get different results if they are not in sync?

Yup, your understanding is correct. A view function is a read contract call. It doesn't change the state so it can be called without gas.

It is usually called by [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_call) method. Below is a sample eth_call request object:

```
{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":null,"to":"0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA","data":"0x70a08231000000000000000000000000271682deb8c4e0901d1a1550ad2e64d568e69909"}, "latest"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

It basically retrieves information from the smart contract account; the result depends on the state of the node.

So if two nodes are out of sync, and you are calling against the "latest" block, you may get different result.

> Or is it that it only returns the state of finalized blocks?

Not really, you can use eth_call to call this function against an old block. In such cases, the function returns the result from the past.

We have a [blog post](https://chainstack.com/deep-dive-into-eth_call/) explaining how eth_call works, hope it may help you.

Happy coding!